# Detecting if path is on a windows mapped network drive

Tags: windows, networking, drive

Is there a simple way to tell if a given path lives on a mapped network drive? Or to tell if a given drive is a mapped network drive?

I hoped they would have a reparse point attribute but GetFileAttributes() returns nothing but a directory flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939.aspx) is one option.

Comment: Good, I missed this function. Suprisingly, it works with any kind of path and not only with the mount point root directory. Thanks!

Comment: Note that GetDriveType will return DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR even for drives mounted interactively by users or by other users, which will result in a "The local device name has a remembered connection" exception when attempting to use it with win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try GetFileAttributesEx() with GetFileExMaxInfoLevel ?

Comment: MSDN still only documents `GetFileExInfoStandard` for `WIN32_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DATA`. `GetFileExMaxInfoLevel` is just an artificial value, all valid values being smaller than that.