# SQLite, prevent a shared network file

Tags: sqlite, networking

We have an application that can use both Postgres and SQLite as its backend, depending on what the customer requires: High load and concurrency, or easy setup.

But I fear that some customers will be too clever for their own good, and to get around the (slightly) complex Postgres installation, they use SQLite, but put the file on a network disk.

Then the inevitable happens and the database gets corrupted, because SQLite is not meant for that, and we have Postgres support for that very reason.

Is there an ideal way to prevent SQLite from working on a network drive? There are some questionable ideas like looking for a \\ at the beginning, or the colon in "C:\" (it's purely a windows app), or parsing for IPs, but none of these are fool-proof and can be circumvented by making a link to a network disk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting if path is on a windows mapped network drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517175/detecting-if-path-is-on-a-windows-mapped-network-drive)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, I just didn't find it.